# Was the Keen weapon enhancement cost ever altered or subject to errata?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, dnd-3e

I suppose the question could be restated: Has *Keen* always been a +1 enhancement in 3e and 3.5e?

I've been playing this game for some years now, as has another player who also frequently runs the game in a very by-the-book manner.

Yet, we were both surprised to see *Keen* as a +1 enhancement in my July 2003 printing of the DMG. We have been playing it as a +2 for so long, but cannot possibly fathom why.

I suppose it's more likely that two people are simply remembering wrong - but I also have no access to D&D 3e material, and perhaps some features of the older system crept into our games, so . . . **At some point during the life of D&D 3e and its revision, did *Keen*'s cost change?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even in my *Dungeon Master's Guide* (2000) for [dnd-3e](/questions/tagged/dnd-3e), page 187 has magic weapon special ability *keen* listed as +1 equivalent. (That can be confirmed with the *3e* SRD that's probably at its most accessible [here](http://www.dragon.ee/30srd/).) I am unaware of any change to the expense of the magic weapon special ability [*keen*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsAW.html#keen) for *D&D 3.5e.*

However, I can imagine a group balking at the inexpensive nature of the magic weapon special ability *keen* in *3e*. Prior to the *3.5* revision, adjustments to critical threat multipliers from, for example, the ability *keen* and the feat [Improved Critical](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#improved-critical) were *cumulative*, making it trivial, for example, to apply both and a few other tricks so that a scimitar threatened a critical hit on almost every strike… if the target's AC was also met or exceeded, of course. Combine this with the pre-revision version of the weapon special ability *vorpal* that triggered on *any* critical hit (rather than the post-revision's natural-20s-only [*vorpal*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsAW.html#vorpal)), and it's a pretty potent recipe. Perhaps your group made such a house rule early, and it became so much a rule for your table that it persisted even post-revision when it was no longer needed?

Comment: It is becoming much more apparent that it is likely my friends and myself have simply been playing the game wrong for years, *with not a single reason for doing it*. I'm going to leave the question open for a day or two longer, in the very off chance that someone is aware of some kind of pricing change - after that, though, it seems appropriate to accept this answer.

Comment: While it’s pretty clear, I think ending the answer with an explicit statement that 3.5 makes such a houserule no longer necessary or desirable would improve the answer. In 3.5, *keen* is often underpowered at +1, and it’s hard to imagine it ever being worth +2 except to truly degenerate tricks (e.g. Lightning Maces). (+1 either way, though.)

Comment: @KRyan It already says, "Perhaps your group made such a house rule early, and it became so much a rule for your table that it persisted even post-revision when it was no longer needed?" Is that insufficient?

Comment: @HeyICanChan It probably is, but it is also in the middle of the paragraph. I think reiterating it as the conclusion is worthwhile. But as said, the answer has my +1 either way.

Comment: @KRyan That's literally the answer's last sentence. I *can* make it its own paragraph, though, if that's what you're after.